# jQuery slideDown() moves everything below downwards. How to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidedown

I have a small problem with jQuery `slideDown()` animation. When this `slideDown()` is triggered, it moves all stuff below downwards too.

How do I make all the stuff below the `<p>` being slid down, remain stationary ?

**Note:**

I would prefer a solution where the change is done to the `<p>` element, or to the `slideDown` call or something. Because in my actual page, there is a *lot* of stuff below the `<p>` being slid down, so changing/re-arranging all of them will take much longer for me ~

**Demo @ JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/A2mmP/24/

**HTML Code:**

```
<section class="subscribe">
    <button id="submitBtn" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
    <p></p>
</section>
<div style="padding-top: 30px;">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>This table moves</td>
            <td>down when</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>slideDown()</td>
            <td>is activated !</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#submitBtn").click(function (event) {
        $(".subscribe p").html("Thanks for your interest!").slideDown();
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.subscribe p {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Try position: absolute; on the p-tag.

Comment: Another alternative would be to set the elements whose are sliding to inside a div with a fixed width and height, with `overflow:hidden;` to prevent its resizing. The page flow would never actualy move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to give a fixed height of your .subscribe.

```
.subscribe {
    height: 50px;
}

.subscribe p {
    margin: 0px;
    display: none;
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xL3R8/

Answer (score 4):

You can [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) that element as `absolute`:

```
.subscribe p {
    display: none;
    position : absolute;        // add this line
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A2mmP/25/

What's happening with your existing code is that the element starts out as `display:none;` so it doesn't take up any space at all until you slide it in and it is changed to `display:block`, hence the movement down of the following elements.

With `position:absolute` it doesn't take up space in that sense, it overlaps: in fact in my updated version of your fiddle you can see a slight overlap into the table underneath - you can obviously tweak margins on the table or whatever to make it fit the way you want.

Comment: its fixes the problem, but causes the slide down text to be left aligned. In my original page, the slide down text is center aligned ..

Comment: Can you fix the alignment problem somehow ?

Comment: So you want it in the horizontal centre of the page? (Your fiddle demo didn't do that...) The simplest way is probably to switch to do it as shown in [user2099829's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17594223/615754), i.e., set the height of the container rather than using `position : absolute;` on the paragraph element, and then centre it however you already do. http://jsfiddle.net/xL3R8/1/

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

We will put the sliding element in a `div` element with a fixed width, preventing the *document flow* from being affected by the slide event.

### HTML

```
<section class="subscribe">
    <button id="submitBtn" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
    <!-- this is the modified part -->
    <div><p></p></div>
</section>
```

### CSS

```css
.subscribe div
{
    /* We force the width to stay a maximum of 22px */
    height:22px;
    max-height:22px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.subscribe div p {
    display: none;
    /* We reset the top margin so the element is shown correctly */
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A2mmP/28/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your CSS, it will render as block and push the other elements down when it slides in.  Set it to be absolutely positioned and change the z-index to be in front, or behind.

```
.subscribe p {
display: none;
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
```

}

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2mmP/27/)

Comment: its fixes the problem, but causes the slide down text to be left aligned. In my original page, the slide down text is center aligned ..

Comment: Can you fix the alignment problem somehow ?

Comment: Not sure exactly where you want it centered.  Use `text-align: center;` to center it in the middle of the page, or use `margin-top: 5px;` to center it between the button and table if you want a dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .subscribe p {
     display: none;
     margin :0px;    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO a good UI practice would be to, remove the subscribe button, and instead show a message there like :
"Hurray! You have been subscribed"
e.g
http://jsfiddle.net/UvXkY/

```
$(function () {
$("#submitBtn").click(function (event) {
    $("#submitBtn").slideToggle('slow', function(){
        $(".subscribe p").html("Thanks for your interest!").slideDown();    
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem your facing is `display:none` which will remove the space for the element `p`

where as `visiblity:hidden` and showing will get ride of this problem

Even though it will not give the proper `slideDown` effects so you can use the position absolute and keep some spaces for the `p` element will solve your problem.

### one of the solution

```
.subscribe p {
   position:absolute;
    display:none;
}

.subscribe
{
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A2mmP/29/)